# os.path.sep.join on two 'args' is not working, why?

Tags: python

I've downloaded this Python code that detects Parkinson from a given set of drawings (spiral and wave drawings).

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from skimage import feature
from imutils import build_montages
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
def quantify_image(image):
    features = feature.hog(image, orientations=9,
        pixels_per_cell=(10, 10), cells_per_block=(2, 2),
        transform_sqrt=True, block_norm="L1")
    return features

def load_split(path):
    imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(path))
    data = []
    labels = []
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
        image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        features = quantify_image(image)
        data.append(features)
        labels.append(label)
    return (np.array(data), np.array(labels))

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--trials", type=int, default=5,
    help="# of trials to run")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
trainingPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "training"])
testingPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "testing"])

print("[INFO] loading data...")
(trainX, trainY) = load_split(trainingPath)
(testX, testY) = load_split(testingPath)

le = LabelEncoder()
trainY = le.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = le.transform(testY)

trials = {}

for i in range(0, args["trials"]):
    print("[INFO] training model {} of {}...".format(i + 1,
        args["trials"]))
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    model.fit(trainX, trainY)
    predictions = model.predict(testX)
    metrics = {}
    cm = confusion_matrix(testY, predictions).flatten()
    (tn, fp, fn, tp) = cm
    metrics["acc"] = (tp + tn) / float(cm.sum())
    metrics["sensitivity"] = tp / float(tp + fn)
    metrics["specificity"] = tn / float(tn + fp)
    for (k, v) in metrics.items():
        l = trials.get(k, [])
        l.append(v)
        trials[k] = l

for metric in ("acc", "sensitivity", "specificity"):
    values = trials[metric]
    mean = np.mean(values)
    std = np.std(values)
    print(metric)
    print("=" * len(metric))
    print("u={:.4f}, o={:.4f}".format(mean, std))
    print("")

testingPaths = list(paths.list_images(testingPath))
idxs = np.arange(0, len(testingPaths))
idxs = np.random.choice(idxs, size=(25,), replace=False)
images = []
for i in idxs:
    image = cv2.imread(testingPaths[i])
    output = image.copy()
    output = cv2.resize(output, (128, 128))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
    image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    features = quantify_image(image)
    preds = model.predict([features])
    label = le.inverse_transform(preds)[0]
    color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "healthy" else (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.putText(output, label, (3, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
        color, 2)
    images.append(output)
montage = build_montages(images, (128, 128), (5, 5))[0]
cv2.imshow("Output", montage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the code there are two arguments: dataset and trials ( dataset helps moving inside the folders without having to create to many paths )

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--trials", type=int, default=5,
    help="# of trials to run")
       args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Now when I've noticed that `load_split()` isn't working since all my arrays are empty:

```
print(trainX)
print(trainY)
print(testX)
print(testY)
```

[image]

And the conclusion I got is that this:

```
trainingPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "training"])
testingPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "testing"])
```

Is not working...
I've tried setting a path and it does work manually, but I'm not quite sure that's the right way to do so even though it does pretty much the same thing.
And that's because I'm not getting the same results as the guy who posted this, they are very different.

How can I fix this ?.

Comment: You want `os.path.join()`.  `os.path.sep.join()` is nonsense - you're applying the normal string `.join` method, the separator character isn't even being used.

Comment: i've said that's it's not my code so...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python too